# Convert Ticks to Datetime value in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, datetime, vba

I have been handed a large number of tables with large integer values for the date and time.

Example:  1382575236393 represents Dec 2, 2013 10:30 PM

My understanding is that this is a tick (nanosecond).  I have been utterly unable to figure out or locate a formula or function that will convert that tick to a date/time value for using in Microsoft Access 2010.

Anyone tackled this before?  I was thinking there'd be a VBA function lurking around somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: You may find this useful: http://able2know.org/topic/70939-1

Answer (score 1):

VBA for the most-part remains frozen in time since the mid-1990s, back when the VB ecosystem was worlds apart from everything else. Thesedays it's a lot more cohesive (e.g. the .NET framework).

Anyway, there is no standard definition of a "tick" - on Unix/POSIX a timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC, in .NET `DateTime.Tick` is one hundred nanoseconds, but `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks` is an arbitrary unit, so it's a bit complicated in-general.

I wasn't sure what scale to use, so I did some division and found it's actually the number of *milliseconds* since the UNIX epoch:

```
Nanoseconds:     1382575236393 / 86400000000000 = 0.01 of a day
100-Nanoseconds: 1382575236393 /   864000000000 = 1.6 days
Microseconds:    1382575236393 /    86400000000 = 16 days
Milliseconds:    1382575236393 /       86400000 = 160002 days (43 years)
Seconds:         1382575236393 /          86400 = 16002028 days (43,841 years!)
```

43 years ago today, co-incidentally, is 1970, so now we know the scale. I'm going to wager since this is obviously based on the 1970-01-01 00:00 epoch it's also going to be in UTC. VBA does not include any built-in functionality for handling timezones (stupid, I know) so I think it's best we assume this is a UTC date value, so you'll need to do your own timezone conversion in your application where appropriate.

You'll need to use 64-bit integers to do this properly, [but there's a problem: only VBA in 64-bit versions of Office 2010 or later include the `LongLong` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264421.aspx), if you're using 32-bit Office or running Office 2007 or earlier then things get a *lot* harder. For now, we'll assume you are running 64-bit Office 2010 or 2013.

Anyway, the solution (with `LongLong`) is to convert the milisecond timestamp into a UNIX timestamp, then let VBA add the seconds to the epoch. Note: *never* add seconds to a year by yourself, because you'll forget things like leap-seconds, leap-years, and other tidbits.

```
Public Function MilisecondUnixTimestampToVBDate(milisecondUnixTimestamp As LongLong) As Date
    Dim unixTimestamp As Long
    unixTimestamp = milisecondUnixTimestamp / 1000

    Dim dt As Date
    dt = DateAdd("s", unixTimestamp , #1/1/1970#)
    MilisecondUnixTimestampToVBDate = dt

End Function
```

Comment: He said *"1382575236393 represents Dec 2, 2013 10:30 PM"* Does your function return that same Date/Time value or does it return Oct 24, 2013 12:40:36 AM?

Comment: @HansUp Thank you for spotting that, and shame on me for not testing it. When I run the function I get the 24th of October 2013 as well. I just assumed because the scale seemed similar to Unix timestamps that it was correct. I think the OP needs to provide more detail.

Comment: Right, something is odd here.  Either he gave us the wrong representative date or those "ticks" are based on something other than  [Unix timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php).

Comment: Hi.  Well this function is 99% there.  I had to mess with the Dim statements and us Double for the inbound.  Then I got this: 12/3/2013 6:30:51 AM.  I am in PST so I modified the function to allow for the time difference and viola!  12/2/2013 10:30:51 PM

Comment: @user3101112 Your (rejected) edit shows you're naively subtracting 8 hours. This code is incorrect because you're not adjusting for PST/DST differences. I strongly recommend processing only UTC dates and times.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier:

```
Public Function TicksToDate(dblMilliseconds As Double) As Date
    TicksToDate = DateAdd("s", dblMilliseconds / 1000, #1/1/1970#)
End Function
```