# Convert Ticks to Date using MS Access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am trying to convert a field in the database that is stored as ticks, I have an access query which i need this field to return a date format.
The following command works in Crystal Reports but i dont know what would be the equivalent of it in MS Access: dbo.udfTicksToDateTime(d.created)

I haven't tried much as I never had to deal with ticks in a system but our new system stores some dates as ticks and it became an issue to run reports on dates. I have a Crystal command provided by someone else that converts the ticks to date but I am unable to establish based on that command what should be entered in Access to get the same result.

Comment: There is no screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Ticks to Datetime value in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577765/convert-ticks-to-datetime-value-in-ms-access)

Comment: for some reason my screenshot didnt get added when posting and i cant edit the post as it says too many edits happening please try again later.... sorry
The screenshot shows MS QUery column in a design view, it has the name of the field in the DB, the Crystal report command i mentioned converts is using the following dbo.udfTicksToDateTime(d.created),  however i do not know what would be the equivalent of that in MS Access

Answer (score 1):

My function `DateDotNet` will do that:

```vb
Public Const HoursPerDay            As Long = 24
Public Const MinutesPerHour         As Long = 60
Public Const SecondsPerMinute       As Long = 60
Public Const MillisecondsPerSecond  As Long = 10 ^ 3
Public Const TicksPerMillisecond    As Long = 10 ^ 5
Public Const SecondsPerHour         As Long = MinutesPerHour * SecondsPerMinute
Public Const SecondsPerDay          As Long = HoursPerDay * SecondsPerHour
Public Const MillisecondsPerMinute  As Long = SecondsPerMinute * MillisecondsPerSecond
Public Const MillisecondsPerDay     As Long = SecondsPerDay * MillisecondsPerSecond

' dotNet.
Private Const DnOffset          As Long = 693593


' Returns the date of a specified dotNet DateTime value with a resolution of 1 ms.
' DotNet can be any value that will return a valid VBA Date value.
'
' Minimum value:   31241376000000000
'   ->  100-01-01 00:00:00.000
' Maximum value: 3155378975999990000
'   -> 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999
'
' 2016-02-08. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateDotNet( _
    ByVal DotNet As Variant) _
    As Date

    Dim Timespan    As Variant
    Dim ResultDate  As Date
    
    Timespan = CDec(DotNet) / TicksPerMillisecond / MillisecondsPerDay - CDec(DnOffset)
    ResultDate = DateFromTimespan(Timespan)
    
    DateDotNet = ResultDate
  
End Function


' Converts a timespan value to a date value.
' Useful only for result date values prior to 1899-12-30 as
' these have a negative numeric value.
'
' 2015-12-15. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateFromTimespan( _
    ByVal Value As Date) _
    As Date
  
    ConvTimespanToDate Value
  
    DateFromTimespan = Value
  
End Function


' Converts a linear timespan value by reference to a date value.
' Example:
'
'   Date     Time  Timespan      Date
'   19000101 0000  2             2
'
'   18991231 1800  1,75          1,75
'   18991231 1200  1,5           1,5
'   18991231 0600  1,25          1,25
'   18991231 0000  1             1
'
'   18991230 1800  0,75          0,75
'   18991230 1200  0,5           0,5
'   18991230 0600  0,25          0,25
'   18991230 0000  0             0
'
'   18991229 1800 -0,25         -1,75
'   18991229 1200 -0,5          -1,5
'   18991229 0600 -0,75         -1,25
'   18991229 0000 -1            -1
'
'   18991228 1800 -1,25         -2,75
'   18991228 1200 -1,5          -2,5
'   18991228 0600 -1,75         -2,25
'   18991228 0000 -2            -2
'
' 2015-12-15. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub ConvTimespanToDate( _
    ByRef Value As Date)
   
    Dim DatePart    As Double
    Dim TimePart    As Double
  
    If Value < 0 Then
        ' Get date (integer) part of TimeSpan shifted one day
        ' if a time part is present as Int() rounds down.
        DatePart = Int(CDbl(Value))
        ' Retrieve and reverse time (decimal) part.
        TimePart = DatePart - Value
        ' Assemble the date and time parts to return a date value.
        Value = CDate(DatePart + TimePart)
    Else
        ' Positive timespan values are identical to date values by design.
    End If
  
End Sub
```

Source: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date)

Comment: thanks for that but i'm not looking for VBA or any other method of doing so.  I'm not an expert but this seems way too complicated.

Comment: It is not complicated, and Access uses VBA only. If you are not looking for any method, then feel free to delete the question.